# Camera is not working on android 8.1 via webview

Tags: android, webview, camera, google-chrome-webview

I have a web app shown in a WebView on Android. It can make photos through the browser interface. This is working on Android versions prior to 8.1, but the thing is, on Android version 8.1 the camera just won't open (nothing is shown instead of ordinary camera view) and when a snapshot is taken the result picture is always black.

I am using the Chrome WebView v71.0.3578.99, but actually the problem exists even on Android WebView. 
All the necessary permissions are successfully granted. 
I couldn't find anything useful in logs, tried WebView debugging but to no avail.